# Why do we say "Fever broke"?

Tags: etymology, phrases

When someone is suffering from fever, at some point in time when it stops or it starts getting better, we say the fever has broken.

> His fever broke last night. He's going to be alright.

What's the etymology behind "break" used in this manner? I couldn't find any other instances of illness or symptoms which use "break" in this manner (except for actual physical breakages).

Comment: We say the heat wave "broke", the cold spell "broke".  We say "If only I could get a break," meaning a change (hopefully for the better) in luck.  Without looking at a dictionary I'd say that that sense of the word means "a significant (and usually beneficial) departure from the previous pattern".

Comment: I always thought "I could get a break" meant break in the same way as "lunch break" or "summer break" or whatever. (As in a temporary change of things). My question is more on why we use "break" for fever (and apparently for heat waves and cold spells) but you don't say "Yeah my cold broke" or "My headache broke"

Comment: I believe you're wrong about "get a break".  Besides, one might actually say "My cold broke" or "My headache broke".

Comment: @Hot Licks While I'm totally unconvinced about the acceptability of 'my cold broke' or 'my headache broke', your previous post is highly relevant, I'm sure. Why isn't the distribution of 'break' in this sense more logical? Come on, this is English. There are probably reasons, but these may be lost in those annoyingly common mists of time.

Comment: Why isn't the distribution of 'break' in this sense more logical? Come on, this is English.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I never heard of *break* being used in respect of colds or headaches. To me, all the usual "meta-metaphoric" usages (*fever, heatwave, cold snap*, etc.) are broadly consistent with things like *His patience finally broke*. I understand the general sense of *[some condition/state of affairs] **broke*** as meaning there was some kind of "phase transition". Which may mean the original condition ceased to apply, but often it just means the outward manifestation of the condition became radically different. Like ocean swells that *break*, thereby becoming waves/rollers/breakers.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. My fever doesn't 'break', either on the way up or down. I do sometimes 'break out in a sweat' (a muckwash in Norfolk), but I 'run' a fever until it 'subsides'.

Comment: @WS2 - It is quite often the case with a fever that there is a sudden change -- over a period of perhaps 2 hours the patient's temperature will peak and then suddenly drop, if not to near normal, to a less worrisome level.  When this happens the fever has "broken".

Comment: @Hot Licks I've never heard of a fever having 'broken'. I have heard of a fever subsiding.

Comment: @WS2 - Well, I guess we run in different circles.  I see you're UK and I'm US, for one.

Comment: Daybreak is the start of the day, but a wave breaking is the end of the wave and a fever breaking is the end of a fever.  Is there a way to know without context whether a given usage of "break" means "beginning" or "end" or something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's based on [definition 5](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/break?searchDictCode=all):

> [NO OBJECT] Undergo a change or enter a new state

When a fever breaks it changes from existing to not existing, or from severe to mild.

Based on just the definition, I suppose it would also be possible to refer to the opposite change as breaking as well. But it's just not how the word is ever used. Several of the senses of this definition are similarly one-directional, e.g. *the clouds broke* means they dispersed, never that they increased.

Comment: It's also worth noting the very first *noun* definition on the same page in your dictionary: *An interruption of continuity or uniformity*. Anything that can metaphorically "break" in this sense has to be something that represented some reasonably "continuous" state for some preceding time. So when it *does* finally enter a new state/phase, you could say it's a bit of a ***break with tradition***.

Comment: Yes, that noun sense is clearly related. I was focusing on verbs, since that's how it's being used in this phrase.

Comment: I upvoted because I thought you'd chosen to cite a particularly apposite definition (me just having referred to "phase transitions" in my comment to the question). But OP did specifically ask about the *etymology*, and I figured this might be best approached by considering that noun definition, since the *first* definition usually represents something close to the "core, original" meaning of a word.