# what do we say when a fever or cold has subsided and it's almost over with?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrasal-verbs

We say pick up or catch a cold when we first get it.

Then when it really intensifies we say smth like "it's settled /settling in", I don't know whatever else people would say..

Anyways, when it subsides and we're feeling better. What is there to say?

Comment: At the point a fever begins to subside we say the fever has "broken". I don't know of a similar term for a cold or other disease.

Comment: I never heard anyone say *My cold is settling in*, but for the third phase it's often *I'm **getting over** a cold*.

Comment: To me, "settling in" implies that the cold is going to be with you for a long time, and is not going away.  I would use "getting over" or "recovering from".

Comment: Other possibility: "on the mend". Example: *I heard you had the flu, but I'm glad to see you're on the mend*.

Comment: "I'm starting to feel human again."

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for *settled down* (not *settled in*)?

Comment: If you’ve already *beat* or *beaten* a cold you’ve probably completely overcome it, but you could say “I’m *beating* this cold” to imply that it has subsided and you’re feeling better, but that the fight is not yet completely over (which makes me think that “I’m fighting a cold” is perhaps another way of saying that the cold has set in).

Comment: I might also say "getting over a cold/flu" but more often would use "I'm getting back to normal" or "almost 100% again".

Answer (score 1):

We would say that the fever [broke](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/break) (definition 5).

Related on [Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/220324/why-do-we-say-fever-broke)